# Strange issue in Google map v2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps

The issue that I am facing [discussed](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816) a lot on Stackoverflowand and on other forums, but I am facing a bit strange.

I have developed a Google map v2 in Android, yesterday it was working fine, today in the morning as I opened the map's app it was not showing the map. I uninstalled the app and regenerate map api's key. Now  it showing the map but not convert Geo-coordinates(latitude, longitude) into string address and arises exception:

```
10-22 18:53:14.980: W/System.err(27510): java.io.IOException: Service not Available
10-22 18:53:14.980: W/System.err(27510):    at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
10-22 18:53:14.980: W/System.err(27510):    at com.ifahja.map.operations.MapOperation.getLocality(MapOperation.java:138)
10-22 18:53:14.980: W/System.err(27510):    at com.ifahja.map.operations.MapOperation.access$1(MapOperation.java:131)
10-22 18:53:14.980: W/System.err(27510):    at com.ifahja.map.operations.MapOperation$AddLocationAsyncTask.doInBackground(MapOperation.java:38)
10-22 18:53:14.980: W/System.err(27510):    at com.ifahja.map.operations.MapOperation$AddLocationAsyncTask.doInBackground(MapOperation.java:1)
10-22 18:53:14.980: W/System.err(27510):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-22 18:53:14.980: W/System.err(27510):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-22 18:53:14.980: W/System.err(27510):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-22 18:53:14.980: W/System.err(27510):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-22 18:53:14.980: W/System.err(27510):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-22 18:53:14.980: W/System.err(27510):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This is my piece of the code where the exception arises.

```
private String getCompleteAddress(Context context,LatLng latLng) {

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
            double latitude = latLng.latitude;
            double longitude= latLng.longitude; 

            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 3);
                String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

                String completeAddress = "";

                if(address != null)
                    completeAddress = completeAddress +address+", ";
                if(city != null)
                    completeAddress = completeAddress +city+", ";
                if(country != null)
                    completeAddress = completeAddress +country;
                return completeAddress;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }
```

**Note:
The app was working fine yesterday and device that I am using for testing is Samsung Tab 3 10.1 
Android v = 4.2.2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting the device, Now it works fine.